# Random Color Generator (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, random, rgb

How would I generate random (R,G,B) colors with minimum components of .5 in a tuple? I'm new at this and fairly confused.

Comment: What do you mean by "minimum components of .5"? Do you mean a minimum intensity of R, G and B each at 50% of maximum?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm not quite sure... I have a large homework assignment that states this explicitly. I'm assuming yes, though.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a homework assignment, it's probably best to avoid just giving you the answer, so here's some basics. You can make a `tuple` with commas (parens only needed when commas might have other meanings, e.g. in function calls, literals of other types, etc., or when the lack of parens would lead to incorrect order of operations), so to make a `tuple` of three elements, you can just do:

```
threetup = a, b, c  # Or (a, b, c)
```

where `a`, `b`, and `c` can be replaced with any source of a value.

For generating the random RGB components, I suggest you take a look at [the `random` module, specifically `random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform) for getting random floating point values.

Answer (score -1):

Somthing like this:

```
import random
def rand_color():
    return "#" + "".join(random.sample("0123456789abcdef", 6))
```

You need to take care of the ".5 minimum" requirement.